# Android Cordova PHONEGAP

Tags: apache-cordova

Quando executo :

```
phonegap create PushNotificationSample --id "com.pushapp" --name "PushNotificationApp"
Creating a new cordova project.
```

Antes pegava normal , porém agora estou tendo esse erro e não consegui resolver faz uns dias .

```
C:\Users\...\Documents\...-work\projects\others\phonegap\testes\push>phonegap create PushNotificationSample --id "com.pushapp" --name "PushNotificationApp"
Creating a new cordova project.


Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (  Error from Cordova Fetch: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "phonegap-template-hello-world@latest"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.0.7:3000
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
npm ERR!  { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.0.7:3000
npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
npm ERR!   address: '192.168.0.7',
npm ERR!   port: 3000 }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\...\.cordova\node_modules\npm-debug.log)
```

Comment: Por um acaso você mudou de rede? está parecendo erro de proxy, tente se possivel conectar em outra fonte de internet para verificar se o comando funciona

Comment: Não mudei não , continuo na mesma ,não sei que problema de proxy é esse.